# Qt Creator - "Cannot create file: Unknown error"

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I bought a new Mac(macOS Big Sur, Apple M1). And I moved all my files from the old Mac to the new one. After downloading Qt creator (I do c++ projects using Qt), whenever I open or close the Qt Creator it shows:

> Cannot create file /Users/[username]/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/devices.xml: Unknown error

Multiple times. And I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Does this folder exist? Can you create that file in that location using a text editor?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you do not have permissions for the **/Users/[username]/.config** folder. Use in terminal:

```
sudo chown -R <username> .config
```

*The answer is from here: ["Cannot create file", "Cannot save session" - unknown error, macOS](https://forum.qt.io/topic/101557/cannot-create-file-cannot-save-session-unknown-error-macos/2)*

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by running the following command in terminal:

```
sudo chown [username] /Users/[username]/.config/
```

Replace [username] with your username.